# How to create simple random array using Numba xoroshiro128p

Tags: random, cuda, numba

I need to get simple example for creating random array using Numba xoroshiro128p within a JIT function. For example final array shell by size(2,4). Link for numba doc [here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.33.0/cuda/random.html)

```
Pseudo code:

minimum = -2
maximum = 2

out_array = random(minimum, maximum, shape(2,4))

Output:
[[ 1.87569628  2.85881711  3.6009965   1.49224129]
 [-3.27321953  1.59090995 -4.66912864 -3.43071647]]
```

Is possible to perform array creation with cuda faster then with numpy? For example:

```
minimum_bound = -1
maximum_bound = 1
vectors_number = 12000000
variable_number = 6

@jit
def random_matrix(vectors_number, variable_number):
    population_generator = np.random.uniform(minimum_bound, 
    maximum_bound, (vectors_number, variable_number))
    return population_generator

population_array = random_matrix(vectors_number, variable_number)
```

With 1200000 vectors to create i get fast the same speed as performing this on cuda.

Comment: You've asked this before -- http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.33.0/cuda/random.html#example

Comment: yes but i don't get any answer :(. I need to see working simple example.

Comment: There is an example right in the documentation you linked to. Are we going to go around in circles again? And reasking the same question because you didn't get an answer isn't allowed here.

Comment: This example is too hard for my. I need only random array, don't know how to extract this from this example.

Comment: So simplify it yourself. It is *8* lines of code. Remove the bits you don't understand and replace them with bit that you can understand and see what they do. If it doesn't work, then come back with a question about why it doesn't work

Comment: I already tried to do this, but with no result. Can't extract what i need from this code. I will try again in the evening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [example](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.33.0/cuda/random.html#example) in the [documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.33.0/cuda/random.html) can be trivially modified to do what you want

```
from numba import cuda
from numba.cuda.random import create_xoroshiro128p_states, xoroshiro128p_uniform_float32
import numpy as np

@cuda.jit
def rand_array(rng_states, out):
    thread_id = cuda.grid(1)
    x = xoroshiro128p_uniform_float32(rng_states, thread_id)
    out[thread_id] = x


threads_per_block = 4
blocks = 2 
rng_states = create_xoroshiro128p_states(threads_per_block * blocks, seed=1)
out = np.zeros(threads_per_block * blocks, dtype=np.float32)

rand_array[blocks, threads_per_block](rng_states, out)
print(out.reshape(blocks,threads_per_block))
```

Comment: This looks good. Hmm.. don't know why i was so struggle with this.

Comment: Is there a way to perform array creation on cuda faster then with numpy?

Comment: numpy does not create cuda arrays

Comment: I know, but is there a faster solution in python then numpy?

Comment: A faster way to create numpy arrays than using numpy?

Comment: nope, what is the fastest way to create big random array?

Comment: But this isn't using numpy. It is compiled python running on the GPU. I've given up trying to understand what you are trying to do or ask here, sorry

Comment: I need to find fastest solution for creating big random array. Using numpy ,CUDA and other tools in python.

Answer (score -1):

Inspired in talonmies answer:

```
@cuda.jit

def random(threads_per_block, blocks):

    def rand_array(rng_states, out): # inside "def random"
        thread_id = cuda.grid(1)
        x = xoroshiro128p_uniform_float32(rng_states, thread_id)
        out[thread_id] = x

    rng_states = create_xoroshiro128p_states(threads_per_block * blocks, seed=1)
    out = np.zeros(threads_per_block * blocks, dtype=np.float32)
    rand_array[blocks, threads_per_block](rng_states, out)
    return out.reshape(blocks,threads_per_block)

# Example of usage: 
matrix100x100 = random(100, 100)
```

### Measuring performance in a Nvidia GTX-650

#### Cuda:

```
%timeit random(100, 100)
```

613 ms ± 2.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#### Numpy:

```
%timeit np.random.rand(100, 100)
```

19.1 ms ± 353 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)